# Why is runtime of deletion in Singly Linked List considered constant O(1)?

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o

When we determine time complexity *we always take into account the worst case scenario.* So why do we not assume the worst case scenario for deletion in a singly linked list (not knowing where the value is, and therefore needing to traverse the entire linked list)???

I'm using this as the "source of truth" http://bigocheatsheet.com/

For example, deletion in an array is considered O(n) because if we delete the first item, then we will need to reassign the index of every other item in the array. If we were to just delete the last item in the array then it would be constant time. But we assume the worst case scenario, which makes sense.

So why would we not do the same for a linked list, and assume the worst case scenario? In that case it seems to me it should be O(n) right?

Comment: a deletion of a node is indeed O(1), but if you want to delete a node with value = 4, you will first need to search it and then delete it. As search is O(n), ends up being O(n) + O(1) = O(n)

Answer (score 2):

Deletion from linked list means you know what element you delete. And all that you do is reassign reference from this element to next. Therefore this operation is O(1).
And of course search in linked list is O(n) as well as in array. But in array even if you know your element you MUST reassign all elements after that.